# How subtract one list from another?

Tags: python, list, filter

Suppose I have got a list of result set of string as below :

```
[ B397 B406 B431 B434 B468 B820 B85 ]
```

I have another list  as below :

```
[ B397 B406 B431 ]
```

If I want to filter out of result set using list B, then return result set as :

```
[ B434 B468 B820 B85 ]
```

How can I filter out?

workings :

```
 new_set = []

    for item in result_set:
            // item found in another list 
                new_set.append(item)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple list comprehension:

```
new_list = [x for x in old_list if x not in filter]
```

You can make the filter faster (O(n) instead of O(n²)) by making `filter` a set